# Голубая полоска в tab

Tags: android, tab

Пытаюсь сделать tab с картинкой вот код:

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

private TabHost tabHost;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
    tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabSpec spec; 
    Intent intent; 
    View view;


    view = createTabView(tabHost.getContext(), "Tab 1"); 
   
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SomeClass1.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_logo_selector)).setContent(intent); 
    

    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SomeClass2.class);
    view = createTabView(tabHost.getContext(), "Tab 2");
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator(view).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SomeClass3.class);
    view = createTabView(tabHost.getContext(), "Tab 3");
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator(view).setContent(intent);        
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
}



private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tab_bg, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
    tv.setText(text);
    return view;
}

}
```

Проблема в том, что при добавлении картинки появляется голубая полоска. Вопрос: как ее убрать? Зарание спасибо.

Для наглядности вот картинка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пробовали `tabHost.setTabStripEnabled(false);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как насчет того чтобы начать использовать более современный TabLayout?

Файл разметки

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_24dp"
        android:tint="@android:color/white" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/secondary_text"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/secondary_text"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_items" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Код Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    drawerToggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager()));
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(PAGE_LIMIT);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    findViewById(R.id.fab).setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Файл адаптера

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private Context context;

public SectionsPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new PersonalCertsFragment();
        case 1:
            return new ContractorsFragment();
        case 2:
            return new CAFragment();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return context.getString(R.string.tab_pers_cert);
        case 1:
            return context.getString(R.string.tab_contractors);
        case 2:
            return context.getString(R.string.tab_ca);
        default:
            return "";
    }
}
```

}